# Remove js file and form with no js go - Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

well then I can not understand why, this code shows a table enclosed in a form that through the checkbox and the press of the specific Excel button, extract all the values ​​of that particular id, and up to here nothing, place the code :

```
<main>
<?php
include '../../connessione.php';
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM clienti";
$query = mysqli_query($connessione, $query_string);
?>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">
<div class="row">
<div style="padding-top: 15px;" class="col-md-6">
<form method="post" action="excel.php">
<input type="submit" name="export" class="btnSearch" value="Estrai in excel" />
</form>
</div>

<div style="padding-top: 15px;" class="col-md-6">
<form action="excel_specifico.php" method="post">
<input style="margin-left: 20px;" type="submit" value="Excel Specifico" class='btnSearch'>
</div>
<div  class="col-md-12">

<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="th-sm">ID
<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</th>
<th class="th-sm">Nome
<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</th>
<th class="th-sm">Cognome
<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</th>
<th class="th-sm">Email
<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</th>
<th class="th-sm">Telefono
<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</th>
<th class="th-sm">Modifica
<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</th>
<th class="th-sm">Elimina
<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</th>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>
<tr>
<td>        
<!-- Material unchecked -->
<div class="form-check">
<?php $cliente_id = $row["cliente_id"]; ?>
<?php echo "<input  type='checkbox' name='estrai[$cliente_id]' value='1' class='form-check-input' id='$cliente_id'>  " ?>
<?php echo "<label class='form-check-label' for='$cliente_id'</label>"; ?> 
</div>
</td>
<td><?php echo $row['nome'] ;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['cognome'] ;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['email'] ;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['telefono'] ;?></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#"><?php echo "<a href='paginadettaglio.php?cliente_id={$row['cliente_id']}' class='btn btn-sm btn-warning '>Modifica</a><br>";?></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#elimina<?php echo $row['cliente_id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> ELIMINA</a></td>
<?php include('modali.php'); ?>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</tfoot>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</div> 
</main>
<script>
// Basic example
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();
$('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/pagination.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".button-collapse").sideNav();
new WOW().init();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.mdb-select').material_select();
});
</script>
```

if this piece of code that is at the bottom of the one I posted, the levo makes me extract everything:

```
<script src="../../js/pagination.js"></script>
```

if instead I put it no. I can not understand. I also put the part that extracts everything in xls:

```
<?php
include '../../connessione.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Contato</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['estrai'])){
            // Definimos o nome do arquivo que será exportado
            $arquivo = 'excel_clienti_selezionati.xls';

            // Criamos uma tabela HTML com o formato da planilha
            $html = '';
            $html .= '<table border="0">';
            $html .= '<tr>';
            $html .= '<td><b>Nome</b></td>';
            $html .= '<td><b>Cognome</b></td>';
            $html .= '<td><b>Email</b></td>';
            $html .= '<td><b>Telefono</b></td>';

            $html .= '</tr>';



            foreach($_POST['estrai'] as $cliente_id => $estrai){
                //echo "cliente_id do item: $cliente_id <br>";
                //Selecionar todos os itens da tabela 
                $result_msg_contatos = "SELECT * FROM clienti WHERE cliente_id = $cliente_id";
                $resultado_msg_contatos = mysqli_query($connessione , $result_msg_contatos);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_msg_contatos)){
                    $html .= '<tr>';
                    $html .= '<td>'.$row["nome"].'</td>';
                    $html .= '<td>'.$row["cognome"].'</td>';
                    $html .= '<td>'.$row["email"].'</td>';
                    $html .= '<td>'.$row["telefono"].'</td>';
                    $html .= '</tr>';
                    ;
                }
            }
            // Configurações header para forçar o download
            header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
            header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
            header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
            header ("Pragma: no-cache");
            header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
            header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"" );
            header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );
            // Envia o conteúdo do arquivo
            echo $html;
            exit;
        }else{
            echo "Nessun ";
        }

        ?>
```

why? I need that file js because it adjusts the search bar and pagination of my table but I need the extraction in xls

Comment: One problem I see is that in your first code block, you’re trying to use jQuery before you’ve included it. Make sure your script includes are done before attempting to use the script, or you’ll end up with errors about undefined variables and methods.

Comment: @Nate how make this sir?

Comment: You see the <script> tag that has the comment “Basic example” in it? It needs to come after any of the <script src=“” > tags. You are using `$(document).ready`, which is a jQuery feature before you actually include the jQuery library (the very next line). Your console probably has errors about how $ is not defined.

Comment: @Nate i put this in the last position of my code, but not work sir

Comment: @Nate i don t know to solve this sir

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: @Nate how to put error on display?

Comment: @Nate if i see only console on google chrome only errors are css

Comment: @Nate sir? are u online?